# How to create a semi changing file path

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a macro code with a fixed file path. I want to change the code in such a manner that most of the path remains fixed, only some part needed to be changed. I want it to pick it from my excel cell.

**Code for file path:**

```
workbooks.open Filename:="Z:\"some folder Name"\P04 (another folder name)\P04 xyz.xlsx
```

In above code I want to change `04` at both places when every month. My plan is I want it to pick 05, 06, 07 and so on from a excel cell. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this - but this works:

```
Dim fname As String
Dim monthno As Long

monthno = Sheets("YourSheetName").Range("A1").Value
fname = "Z:\some folder Name\P" & Format(monthno, "00") & " (another folder name)\P" & Format(monthno, "00") & " xyz.xlsx"
workbooks.Open fname
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you please briefly explain what is happening in monthno =

Comment: `monthno` picks up the value held in the cell `A1` - eg. 4 and formats it to a string using `00` as the template - so 4 becomes 04.

Comment: Its working like a charm, you are superb. Thanks a lot.